# Two factor authentication using Identity server 4 asp.net Core, how to increase the expiry time from default 6 minutes to 30 minutes

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, two-factor-authentication

Asp.Net Core Identity Server 4 is used for authentication. Am using the Identity Server 4 DLL in project and all methods like UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync.
I need to change the default expiry time from 6 minutes to 30 minutes? Please let me know what code change need to be done.

I have tried all given in below link but not working
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity.

Only 2 factor authentication needs to be changed, other links like Password Reset and Send Invite expiry time should not be changed.

This is my ConfigureServices in Startup.cs file.

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:MaxFailedLoginAttempt")?.Get() ?? 5;
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:UnlockTime")?.Get() ?? 24);
options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/842342/extend-the-2fa-token-expiration-in-asp-net-core).